# How do I target just one instance of a nested repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is probably pretty basic, but I'm going round in circles.

I have a nested controller in a ng-repeat - I would like to trigger an event in an instance of the repeat that will affect only the nested controller in that instance, not the nested controller in all instances.

Here is a basic example to try and make things clearer:

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
        <p>{{comments.body}}</p>
        <a href ng-click="showComments(post.id)">Show comments</a>
      </div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular) {

        var posts = Restangular.all('posts');

        posts.getList().then(function(posts) {
            $scope.posts = posts;
        });

        $scope.showComments = function(id) {
            $scope.$broadcast('SHOW_COMMENTS', id);
        };

  });


angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CommentsCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular) {

    $scope.$on('SHOW_COMMENTS', function(event, id) {

            var post = Restangular.one('posts', id);

            post.get().then(function(post) {
              $scope.comments = post.comments;
            });

    });

  });
```

What would happen in this example is that all instances of the comments controller would be populated with the same comments - I just need to be able to target the relevant one. I'm sure I'm missing something pretty fundamental, and probably going about this the wrong way.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you please setup a plunker, it would be easy to solve issue using plunker

Comment: Why is the `showComments()` method in `PostsCtrl` and not in `CommentsCtrl` where it belongs? Would solve the problem, and wouldn't need any event. Otherwise, you can simply check f the broadcasted post ID is the same as the id of the post in the scope of the CommentsCtrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're broadcasting "SHOW_COMMENTS" to all repeated posts. You need to isolate the scope per Post.

Isolate the scope using ng-controller="PostCtrl".

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
        <p>{{comments.body}}</p>
        <a href ng-click="showComments()">Show comments</a>
      </div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Move show comments from PostsCtrl to PostCtrl.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.showComments = function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('SHOW_COMMENTS', $scope.post.id);
    };
  });
```

Do you really need to use events? You could use ng-if instead.

Your comments are embedded in each Post anyway so why request them again. In this case you could do like something this...

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <a href ng-click="toggleComments()">Show comments</a>
    <div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl" ng-if="showComments">
      <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
        <p>{{comments.body}}</p>
      </div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Toggle comments...

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.showComments = false;

     $scope.toggleComments = function() {
        $scope.showComments = !$scope.showComments;
     };
  });
```

Comment: That's great, all working now - thanks for the help Tim.